# 'gensim' is not recognized in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, gensim

PyCharm can't find gensim that is listed in "anaconda list". in anaconda list I can see gensim but it does not exist in project interpreter!!!
I'm using paython version 3.7. I have no problem with other libraries, the problem is just in gensim installation

[image: anaconda list]

[image: project interpreter list]

If anyone has any advice, I'd appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried installing the package from Pycharm?

Comment: If you notice, Flask isn't there either, so it looks like you definitely are using different interpreters

Comment: Yes I have tried through Pycharm too.
yes Flask isn't there, but i have only two "interpreters"!!!,  "anaconda list" is similar to none of them!!

Comment: `anaconda` runs it's own Python interpreter. I'm not sure what "other two" you have or where they are located based on your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two lists seem to come from different interpreters. Most likely you have not selected in PyCharm correct interpreter and hence the error. Please check the [PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) for information on how to configure interpreter.

Comment: That's exactly my problem I think.... i have only two "interpreters" and i can't see 'gensim' in those interpreters!! and even some of others libraries!! but so far I have no problem with installations

Comment: Which OS are you running? Windows?

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: Start then Anaconda prompt and switch to the environment with gensim (make sure it's there). Next, run `where python` to find path to the interpreter. Put the same path in PyCharm.